# Installing AUTO-07P on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, bash, software-installation, bashrc

I am trying to install the [numerical continuation software AUTO-07P](https://sourceforge.net/projects/auto-07p/) on a new installation of Ubuntu 18.04.

After installing all the required packages I had to copy `.bashrc` to the home folder, and then to add the line

```
source $HOME/auto/07p/cmds/auto.env
```

at the end of the `.bashrc` file. However, I got the following error message:

```
setenv: command not found
bash: /home/ohm18/auto/07p/cmds/auto.env: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: /home/ohm18/auto/07p/cmds/auto.env: line 5: `set    path=($AUTO_DIR/cmds $AUTO_DIR/bin  $path)'
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setenv` command is `csh` builtin command and you are using another shell. If csh is already installed you can enter that shell just by typing 'csh' at the bash prompt.

Path in BASH looks like

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

> I had to copy .bashrc to the home folder, and then to add the line `source $HOME/auto/07p/cmds/auto.env`

Where does it say that? The included PDF states you need to do that IF you are using csh.

> 1.1 Installation.
>
> The AUTO file auto07p-0.9.1.tar.gz is available via http://cmvl.cs.concordia.ca/auto. Here
>   it is assumed that you are using the Unix (e.g. bash) shell and that the file auto07p-0.9.1.tar.gz
>   is in your main directory. See below for OS-specific notes.
>   While in your main directory, enter the commands gunzip auto07p-0.9.1.tar.gz, followed
>   by tar xvfo auto07p-0.9.1.tar. This will result in a directory auto, with one subdirectory,
>   auto/07p. Type cd auto/07p to change directory to auto/07p. Then type ./configure , to
>   check your system for required compilers and libraries. Once the configure script has finished
>   you may then type make to compile AUTO and its ancillary software. The configure script is
>   designed to detect the details of your system which AUTO requires to compile successfully. If
>   either the configure script or the make command should fail, you may assist the configure script
>   by giving it various command line options. Please type ./configure --help for more details.
>   Upon compilation, you may type make clean to remove unnecessary files.
>   To run AUTO you need to set your environment variables correctly. Assuming AUTO
>   is installed in your home directory, the following commands set your environment variables
>   so that you will be able to run the AUTO commands, and may be placed into your .login,
>   .profile, or .cshrc file, as appropriate. **If you are using a sh compatible shell, such as sh,
>   bash, ksh, or ash enter the command source $HOME/auto/07p/cmds/auto.env.sh. On the
>   other hand, if you are using a csh compatible shell, such as csh or tcsh, enter the command
>   source $HOME/auto/07p/cmds/auto.env.**

Why did you pick the last part of that sentence and not the 1st part?

Comment: Thanks for spotting my error, I got confused there...

Comment: Can happen ;)  good you got it sorted.